# Socket reads echo'ing back old sends?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to do a very simple read/write to an embedded device using sockets in Python. For some reason, the sock.recv() command is returning my sent string instead of my expected return string. Here is how I open the socket:

```
HOST1 = '192.168.1.201'
PORT1 = 4998
sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST1, PORT1))

while (1):
    sock.sendall("getstate,1:1\r")
    state1 = sock.recv(32)
    sock.sendall("getstate,1:2\r")
    state2 = sock.recv(32)
    print "states:", state1, state2
```

The expected return string (state1 or state2) is the current device state and is of the form "state,1:1,0" (off) or "state,1:1,1" (on). However, I frequently get back my own command (the "getstate.." command) instead of the return string. I thought that sock.sendall() would clear out the send buffer? I'm a noob with sockets, so any help would be appreciated. I've searched pretty extensively on this, and I can't find anyone who is having this same problem. I've tested the remote device manually and it always sends back the expected return string, so I believe the problem must be in the way I am using the sockets.

Comment: The way you're using those sockets is perfectly sensible. Have you tried using `\r\n` or `\n` instead of `\r`. Maybe the device is echoing your request as an error?

Comment: Try using netcat (`nc 192.168.1.201:4998`) to talk to the server interactively, to see if it really responds the way you're expecting.

Comment: Meanwhile, it's not even a matter of "clear[ing] out the send buffer"; the send and receive buffers are entirely separate things, and unless there's a huge bug in your OS or drivers, there's no way anything can "leak" from one to the other. Whatever you're seeing in `recv` was sent by the other side.

Comment: One more possibility: Does the device's protocol actually guarantee that `\r` is a delimiter in one direction, and all messages are exactly 32 bytes in the other?

Comment: @abarnert: `.recv(32)` can return less than `32` bytes (including blocking sockets). It can also return 2 messages at once (or 1.3 messages, etc). Usually `.recv()` is called in a loop until EOF or a delimiter found (a line-based protocol) or given number of bytes read (e.g., netstring) depending on the protocol (buffering the tail for the next message in the later two cases).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Of course. But the right way to solve the problem depends on what the protocol is. If it's exactly 32 bytes per message, all you need is a simple `readall` that loops, blocking, until it's got exactly 32 bytes; if it's something more complicated, you need more than that. That's why I started with this question.

Comment: You may also use `Wireshark` or any network listener program to debug both what you're sending and what you're receiving. Do you have some info about the code running at the embedded device? or any info about its behavior?

Comment: The ideal response would be fixed length "state,1:1,1", but there are potentially error messages that would be a different length. For now, I was parsing the string for delimiters and checking if isdigit() gave me a good numeric state. I've tried using a test utility supplied with the device and it always shows a good reply. I'm reading the man page for NC to see how I can use it for testing. I will look into Wireshark as well. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: OMG, I'm an idiot. jleahy figured it out indirectly. The read buffer hadn't been cleared from a prior send command. The reason I am reading the state is to make sure the state that I previously set was handled correctly. In a prior line of code I had done this: s.sendall("setstate,1:1,0\r") which echo's back my command to confirm that it was received. But, I wasn't reading this return string. So, when I then asked for the state using getstate and read for the return I was first getting the echo back from the prior setstate. Doh! Thank you all so much!!